# Optimizing Summarize in DAX

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, tabular

I have this DAX formula that gives me a count of id that appear on the fact table in a month, averaged over the year. I can put this measure is a table ad it's unpacked by row with no issues (by adding variables from dimensions)

```
Measure:= AVERAGEX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        CALCULATETABLE(fact_table;FILTER('Time_Dimension';'Time_Dimension'[Last_month] <> "LAST"));
         Time_Dimension[Month Name];
        "Count";DISTINCTCOUNT(fact_table[ID])
    );
    [Count]
)
```

But it's terrible slow (I have 3 measures like this on a single table) and the fact table is big (like 300Million rows big)

I was reading that SUMMARIZE perform really bad with aggregations and It should be replaced with SUMMARIZECOLUMNS.
I wrote this formula

```
Measure_v2:= AVERAGEX(
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
        Time_Dimension[Month Name];
        FILTER(Time_Dimension;
            Time_Dimension[Month Name]<>"LAST"
        );
        "Count";DISTINCTCOUNT(fact_table[ID])
    )
    [Count]
)
```

And it works when I visualize the measure as it is, but when I try to put it in a context (like the table above) it gives me the error "Can't use SUMMARIZECOLUMN and ADDMISSINGITEMS() in this context" How can I make a sustainable optimization from the original SUMMARIZE function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before optimizing SUMMARIZE, I would re-visit the overall approach. If your goal is to calculate average fact count per year-month, there is a simpler (and faster) way.

```
[ID Count]:=CALCULATE(COUNT('fact_table'[ID]),'Time_Dimension'[Last_month] <> "LAST") 

[Average ID Count]:=AVERAGEX( VALUES('Time_Dimension'[Year_Month]), [ID Count`])
```

assuming that:

- you have year-month attribute in your time dimension;
- IDs in your fact table are unique (and therefore, simple count is
  enough)

If this solution does not solve your problem, then please post your data model - it's hard to optimize without knowing the data structure.

On a side note, I would remove ID field from the fact table. It adds no value to the model, and consumes huge amounts of memory. Your objective can be achieved by simply counting rows:

```
[Fact Count]:=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('fact_table'),'Time_Dimension'[Last_month] <> "LAST")
```

Comment: I changed the variable names so in reality ID is something like a "shop id" linked to a shop dimension and it isn't primary key (there are duplicates, hence the DISTINCTCOUNT above). I'll try your solution on another version of the measure grouped by date instead of month because I don't have month-year in my time dimension at the moment.

Comment: Tried on the daily and works really well, for the montly I could create a column month-year by concatenation. If you have more advices on optimization please do. Thanks